# i am not able to render images with pug view template

Tags: node.js, templates, view, pug

doctype html
html(lang="en")
head
meta(charset="UTF-8")
meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
title Document
body
div
img(src='./tree.jpg' alt='login' style='width:100px; height:100px;')
#form
form(action="/" method="post")
label(for="name") name
input(type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="okay")
input(type="submit" value="dingoo")

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Install the pug-loader:

```
npm install @webdiscus/pug-loader --save-dev
```

In webpack config module add following rules:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        loader: '@webdiscus/pug-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|ico)/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'assets/images/[name].[hash:8][ext]',
        },
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

In pug use require() for image:

```
img(src=require('./path/to/tree.jpg)')
```

Generated HTML:

```html
<img src="/assets/images/tree.23fe5de2.jpg">
```

This works fine with the `@webdiscus/pug-loader`.